# Creating new bash command for Sublime Text 2

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, sublime-text-2

I'm trying to get Sublime Text 2's command line alias working.

The [instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) make perfect sense: Run

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

So, in ~/bin, `subl` exists. However, even when I restart terminal, the command 'subl' is not found. The path specified to the application's subl file is correct, I've verified that. Logging out does not fix it.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Have you added `~/bin/subl` to your `$PATH`?

Comment: Sure haven't, I'm checking how to do this (first time for everything), but I'll gladly accept it in answer format!

Comment: @Gavin Do you have both `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` or only the former? Are there other occurrences of `PATH` in either of these files (or wherever that ruby stuff is set)? Does `~/bin/subl` have the executable flag set?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure `~/bin` is added to your `$PATH`

Put this is your `.bash_profile`

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export PATH
```

and it should be available next time you open a shell

Comment: @Gavin - Another thing occurred to me. I'm not sure OSX uses `.bash_profile` by default. You could put the lines in your `.bashrc` instead.

Comment: OS X Terminal by default uses a login shell, so `.bash_profile` is correct here.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 7):

if you are using RVM, do this:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a shell script like this into /usr/local/bin/ and I call it subl

```
#!/bin/bash
#
growlnotify -t "Sublime Text 2" -m "Sublime Text 2 is starting up."
/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

then I made the one for the superuser like this and I call it susubl

```
#!/bin/bash
#
growlnotify -t "Su > Sublime Text 2" -m "Sublime Text 2 is starting up as superuser."
sudo /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

Answer (score 1):

for mac users: Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the `Applications` folder, and that you have a `~/bin` directory in your path, you can run:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

and then:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

and add the folowwing lines:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export PATH
```

- If you don't have a .bash_profile file in your user root you can make one in Sublime Text (or some other editor) and save it to your home folder with the above code. Then relaunch Terminal.